How to align SVG icons in text without using flexbox while maintaining truncation?


.box {
  width: 230px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

svg {
  /* The size of the icon can vary */
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}
<div class="box">
  <span class="text truncate">
    This is text
    <svg width="48" height="48" viewBox="0 0 48 48">
      <path id="icon-info" d="M22 34h4V22h-4v12zm2-30C12.95 4 4 12.95 4 24s8.95 20 20 20 20-8.95 20-20S35.05 4 24 4zm0 36c-8.82 0-16-7.18-16-16S15.18 8 24 8s16 7.18 16 16-7.18 16-16 16zm-2-22h4v-4h-4v4z">
      </path>
    </svg>
    and it should truncate
  </span>
</div>



In this example we have some Text with an SVG in it. I gave the SVG a height & width of 24px but that size may change.
Is there a way to consistently center the SVG regardless of the size of the SVG without breaking the truncation? (Adding display: flex breaks the ellipsis truncation).
I have also tried the strategy listed here in this blog post but it requires the SVG to have height/width of 1em, if I increase that size I'm not sure how to dynamically calculate the top value.

Change the viewbox to the real values used in the path (4 4 40 40 not 0 0 48 48),
Add css vertical-align.
Do not duplicate css width and height attributes


.box {
  width         : 230px;
  border        : 1px solid black;
  overflow      : hidden;
  text-overflow : ellipsis;
  white-space   : nowrap;
  }
svg {
  width          : 20px;  /* height is the same because aspect-ratio is 1/1 on default */
  vertical-align : bottom;
  }
<div class="box">
  <span class="text truncate">
    This is text
    <svg viewBox="4 4 40 40">
      <path id="icon-info" d="M22 34h4V22h-4v12zm2-30C12.95 4 4 12.95 4 24s8.95 20 20 20 20-8.95 20-20S35.05 4 24 4zm0 36c-8.82 0-16-7.18-16-16S15.18 8 24 8s16 7.18 16 16-7.18 16-16 16zm-2-22h4v-4h-4v4z">
      </path>
    </svg>
    and it should truncate
  </span>
</div>



.

Also with em unit...  -> vertical-align : sub; or vertical-align : middle;



.box {
  font-size     : 16px;
  width         : 14em;
  border        : 1px solid black;
  overflow      : hidden;
  text-overflow : ellipsis;
  white-space   : nowrap;
  }
svg {
  width          : 4em;  /* === height  (aspect-ratio: 1/1 on default) */
  vertical-align : middle;
  }
<div class="box">
    This is text
    <svg viewBox="4 4 40 40">
      <path id="icon-info" d="M22 34h4V22h-4v12zm2-30C12.95 4 4 12.95 4 24s8.95 20 20 20 20-8.95 20-20S35.05 4 24 4zm0 36c-8.82 0-16-7.18-16-16S15.18 8 24 8s16 7.18 16 16-7.18 16-16 16zm-2-22h4v-4h-4v4z">
      </path>
    </svg>
    and it should truncate
</div>




I am experimenting with your code, how does this answer change if we adjust the height/width of the icon?

@jmancherje   the height/width respect thr same viewbox proportion : 1 pixel for 2 svg coordinates values. the viewbox is 4 4 40 40 not 0 0 48 48

Sorry let me re ask the question. If we change the "width" to another value, it's no longer centered. How do we adjust the answer to center the icon if the size of the icon changes? https://jsfiddle.net/7bazsqeu/2/

@jmancherje everything is played on the css vertical-align but it is still necessary that the drawing in the SVG itself is in agreement with its viewbox!  so use vertical-align : middle;  see my second snippet

Yes — vertical-align: middle.


.box {
  width: 230px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

svg {
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.b1 svg {
  width: 24px;
}

.b2 svg {
  width: 48px;
}

.b3 svg {
  width: 96px;
}
<div class="box b1">
  <span class="text truncate">
    This is text
    <svg viewBox="0 0 48 48">
      <path id="icon-info" d="M22 34h4V22h-4v12zm2-30C12.95 4 4 12.95 4 24s8.95 20 20 20 20-8.95 20-20S35.05 4 24 4zm0 36c-8.82 0-16-7.18-16-16S15.18 8 24 8s16 7.18 16 16-7.18 16-16 16zm-2-22h4v-4h-4v4z">
      </path>
    </svg>
    and it should truncate
  </span>
</div>

<div class="box b2">
  <span class="text truncate">
    This is text
    <svg viewBox="0 0 48 48">
      <path id="icon-info" d="M22 34h4V22h-4v12zm2-30C12.95 4 4 12.95 4 24s8.95 20 20 20 20-8.95 20-20S35.05 4 24 4zm0 36c-8.82 0-16-7.18-16-16S15.18 8 24 8s16 7.18 16 16-7.18 16-16 16zm-2-22h4v-4h-4v4z">
      </path>
    </svg>
    and it should truncate
  </span>
</div>


<div class="box b3">
  <span class="text truncate">
    This is text
    <svg viewBox="0 0 48 48">
      <path id="icon-info" d="M22 34h4V22h-4v12zm2-30C12.95 4 4 12.95 4 24s8.95 20 20 20 20-8.95 20-20S35.05 4 24 4zm0 36c-8.82 0-16-7.18-16-16S15.18 8 24 8s16 7.18 16 16-7.18 16-16 16zm-2-22h4v-4h-4v4z">
      </path>
    </svg>
    and it should truncate
  </span>
</div>



